# OptaPlanner / vehicle routing / deleting customers

Tags: java, drools, drools-planner, optaplanner

I am using OptaPlanner to optimize a vehicle routing problem very similar to the provided example. Since I have several hundred stops, the optimization takes a couple of hours.

Here is my issue: Sometimes customers cancel orders. In this case, I don't want to run the whole optimization process from the beginning again and wait again for hours. I would like to delete these customers from the solved XML file and start the optimization from there. Is there a way to adjust the solved XML file?

I tried to set the demand to 0 but I still have vehicles approaching this customer, even if the demand is 0.

Would be great if you would have an idea here. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In the docs, take a look at [the section real-time planning](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#realTimePlanning). It even has code that shows how a computer gets deleted from cloudBalancing.

Note: make sure that you remove the customer entity from all other customers that point to it (with previous/next) too or you'll suffer from score corruption. There was a question about this recently on the mailing list.